# Flutter audioplayers package: Android vs iOS

Tags: flutter, audio, timer, audio-player

I'm quite new into flutter and coding in general. I'm trying to build a meditation app, that plays a bell every 30/60/120... seconds, depends on user input. My code works perfectly fine on Android device, but when running on iOS, it plays bell only once and doesn't play anymore. Any suggestions please? Thank you!

```
    if (((widget.meditation.notification) != 0) &&
        ((_time % widget.meditation.notification) == 0)) {
      print('notification $_time');
      audioCache.play('audio/bell.wav');
    }
```

Comment: Which version of the package do you use? Upgrade it with: ^0.17.0

Comment: @Akif yea, I'm using this version

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution, simply everytime .release() must be called.

By default, the player will be release once the playback is finished or the stop method is called.

This is because on Android, a MediaPlayer instance can be quite resource-heavy, and keep it unreleased would cause performance issues if you play lots of different audios.

On iOS and macOS this doesn't apply, so release does nothing.